# My javascript function is not firing from the code behind 

Tags: asp.net

hai ,

I have a javascript function named as sss() . I want to call it from the code behind.

```
 function sss() {
          $("#div-TableContent").show("slow");
          alert("its Works"); 
          };
```

I used this code

```
 Private Sub dataGridView_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles dataGridView.RowEditing
        If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("sss")) Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alert", "sss();", True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

but it is not  firing when the grid is in the ajax update panel. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Ajax component, you should write something like:

```
If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("sss")) Then   
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "sss", "sss();", True)   
End If
```

The `Page.ClientScript` has been obsoleted. Also note that the third parameter is a key, and you were checking the wrong one.

Answer (score -1):

You could put in a Panel and inject some javascript into it:

```
<asp:Panel id="javascripInjectorPanel" runat="server">
```

and on your code behind, do:

```
javascriptInjectorPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type=\"text/javascript\">sss();</script>"));
```

when the page refreshed, it should get executed. Might be worth experimenting with ASp.ENT AJAX, not sure how that would work.

Comment: I do wish if people take the time to down-vote answers, they would explain why. It helps no-one and de-motivates my help.

Comment: I used update panel for avoiding refreshing of the page. by using asp panel can i do the same thing?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about. As long as the asp:Panel is within the Update Panel, it will get sent to the client, but I don't know if it will run. I just haven't tried this method. 

I tend to use Telerik's controls, and this is a technique recommended by them before they implemented better support for this behaviour in the RadAjaxManager control, which I now use. So never needed it. Worth a try, though.